# Most efficient way to loop in a XamDataGrid

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I am evaluating the performance of the XamDataGrid provided by Infragistics. In particular, i'm focusing on the programmatic selection of 500k record in a table of 1 million records. To do that i'm currently doing the following:

```
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        var recordsToSelect = new List<DataRecord>(500000);
        s.Start();
        foreach (DataRecord rec in ODataGrid.Records)
        {
            if (rec.Index % 2 == 0)
                recordsToSelect.Add(rec);
        }
        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed);
        s.Restart();
        ODataGrid.SelectedItems.Records.AddRange(recordsToSelect.ToArray(), false, true);
        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed);
```

the results are the following:

```
00:00:14.3122651 for the loop
00:00:00.8765741 to apply the selection
```

The problem is clearly the loop. I wonder, since i'm binding a DataTable as item source, and since the loop on a DataTable is 10x faster the the loop on the XamDataGrid.Recordsif there is a way to convert the DataRow in a DataRecord, or if there is a faster way to reach the goal of the function i exposed before

**EDIT** :

I was able to imporove performance doing:

```
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        var recordsToSelect = new List<DataRow>(500000);
        s.Start();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow rec in d.Rows)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                recordsToSelect.Add(rec);
            i++;
        }
        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed);
        s.Restart();
        DataRecord[] dr = ODataGrid.GetRecordsFromDataItems(recordsToSelect.ToArray(), false);
        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed);
        s.Restart();
        ODataGrid.SelectedItems.Records.AddRange(dr, false, true);
        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed);
```

with these times elapsed

```
00:00:00.0812110
00:00:08.2830562
00:00:01.1774925
```

the problem is that the creation of the DataRecord array is the slowest part

Answer (score 0):

Why do you reach your item source over a datagrid? You can use MVVM approach to get your item source as ObservableCollection or List. From your view model, you can reach the data source and as well as your selected items.

Comment: i'm just doing performance test, and i need to figure out which is the best approach, so in this stage i'm not creating any real project. I just slapped a XamDataGrid in a wpf appl and filled it with a datatable binded to it. SelectedItems of XamDataGrid, is not settable, you need to access to SelectedItems.Records to do anything

Comment: Yeah, it is clear. As long as you use directly UI Elements to get your data, index etc., you could expect different results regarding perfomance. In any case best approach would be separating UI from the logic.

Comment: in this phase it's not important to separate UI from logic. It's important to me, which is the fastest way to use .SelectedItems.Records.AddRange, since it need an array of records, and looping through the records is slower then looping through a datatable